# Phonegap Windows Phone 8 Build Error

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to deploy an app to a Windows Phone 8 device, compiling it with phonegap's 3.0.0-0.14.4 command line tools, but I keep getting this error message while trying to build it:

```
phonegap local run wp8 -V

[error] An error occurred while building the wp8 project.
WARNING: [ --debug | --release ] not specified, defaulting to debug...
Building Cordova-WP8 Project:
        Configuration : Debug
        Directory : C:\Users\Robson\Documents\Phonegap\project\platforms\wp8
Compiling this solution's projects one at a time. 
To enable parallel compilation, add "/m" option
  Project -> C:\Users\Robson\Documents\Phonegap\project\platforms\wp8\Bin\
Debug\br.com.project.dll
  Begin application manifest generation
  No changes detected. Application manifest file is up to date
  Begin Xap packaging
MSBUILD : error : Xap packaging failed. Failed to package file 'C:\Users\Robson\
Documents\Phonegap\project\platforms\wp8\www\.svn\entries'. Could not find the
specified file. [C:\Users\Robson\Documents\Phonegap\project\platforms\
wp8\Project.csproj]
ERROR: MSBuild failed to create .xap when building cordova-wp8 for debugging.
```

If I open the Solution with Visual Studio Express for Windows Phone, there is a reference to this ".svn" directory, which doesn't exists on the hard drive. That explains the error.

When I delete the reference and build it on Visual Studio, I'm able to deploy it to the phone. If I delete the reference and try to build it with phonegap's command line tools, the error comes up again. It looks like phonegap's command line tools is creating this broken reference to the ".svn" directory.

Is there any difference on deploying it by phonegap's command line tools or by Visual Studio?

Is there a way to solve this phonegap's command line build issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

check your C:\Users\Robson\Documents\Phonegap\project\merges folder for the .svn folder and remove if its in there.
cheers

Comment: The merge directory is empty :(

Comment: This issue doesn't happen compiling it with phonegap 3.4.0, it's probably related to something with version 3.0.0-0.14.4.